# creating a partial-like object with dynamic arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a partial function but with dynamic arguments that are stored as class attributes and changed accordingly. Something like the following code:

```
from functools import partial

def foo(*args, msg):
    print(msg)

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.functions = dict()
        self.functions['foo'] = partial(foo, msg=self.msg)

    def foo_method(self, *args):
        return self.functions['foo'](*args)

b =Bar('1')
b.foo_method()
b.msg = '2'
b.foo_method()
```

Only, of course, both statements will print '1' as the partial object fixes the arguments. The only alternative I found was changing the attribute to a property and manually changing the partial attributes with the setter:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self._msg = None
        self.functions = dict()
        self.functions['foo'] = partial(foo)
        self.msg = msg

    def foo_method(self, *args):
        return self.functions['foo'](*args)

    @property
    def msg(self):
        return self._msg

    @msg.setter
    def msg(self, msg):
        self._msg = msg
        self.functions['foo'].keywords['msg'] = msg
```

I would like to know if there is a more "pythonic" / efficient way to do this, since I really don't need to use properties except for this workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lambda` instead of `partial` for deferred (or often referred to as "lazy") evaluation of the arguments, so that `self.msg` is not evaluated until the function is called:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.functions = dict()
        self.functions['foo'] = lambda *args: foo(*args, msg=self.msg)

    def foo_method(self, *args):
        return self.functions['foo'](*args)
```

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just storing a reference to the passed function and constructing the call on the spot? i.e.:

```
class Bar:

    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.foo = foo  # a reference to foo, not needed here but used as an example

    def foo_method(self, *args):
        return self.foo(*args, msg=self.msg)  # or just: foo(*args, msg=self.msg)
```

Comment: I didn't specify it it in the original question, but the thing is the foo_method is a superclass method. The idea was to mantain the method signature between classes (i.e. functions['foo'] should be always of the form lambda *args: result), so any adjustments should be made in __init__

Comment: @Mstaino - That doesn't sound like a good idea, I'd suggest rethinking your design before complicating it further. That being said, if there is a valid reason to do it that way, use lambdas as as in [blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52407367/).

Answer (score 1):

A thing that seems to be working as well is defining the function to work with a class attribute.

You can then define a function using `partial` with one of the arguments being the class.

```py
class myContex:
    a = 5
    
def my_fun(context, b, c):
    print(context.a, b, c)
    
my_fun_partial = partial(my_fun, myContext)
my_fun_partial(4,7)

# Output: 5 4 7

myContext.a = 50
my_fun_partial = partial(my_fun, myContext)
my_fun_partial(4,7)

# Output: 50, 4, 7
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible way I can think of would be just constructing a dict and passing it double-starred to the function to unpack.

Something like:

```
def some_func(msg, some_arg=None):
    print("Hello world") # ignore the msg for now

call_args = {}
call_args['some_arg'] = 2 # single field
call_args.update({'msg': 1, 'stuff': [2,3,4]}) # multiple at once

some_func(**call_args)
```

Right now, some_func will throw a TypeError because we've passed more args than the function takes. You could work around this either by having the function accept **kwargs in the signature, trimming down the arguments you don't expect or some other approach.

For now, continuing the last session:

```
call_args = {'msg': 'abc'} # let's get rid of those extra args
some_func(**call_args) # => prints 'Hello world'
```